# How to change commit name in Power Apps in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, powerapps

I have a question: how and is it possible to change the Commit name when committing via Power Apps? I mean adding a message like from the commit-m console
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to change the commit name when committing via Power Apps.
But you can change the commit name from git command. You need to `force` push to DevOps repo to overwrite the commit.

1. To change the last commit name, you can use the `git commit --amend` command. This will let you edit the commit message in a text editor and save the new name. However, this will create a new commit object with a different ID, so you will need to force push the branch to the remote repo using `git push --force origin yourBranch`.
2. To change a specific commit name, you can use the `git rebase -i` command. This will let you rewrite the history of your repo and edit any commit message in an interactive mode. You will need to specify the commit ID or the number of commits you want to rebase. For example, `git rebase -i HEAD~3` will let you edit the last three commits. You will also need to force push the branch to the remote repo after rebasing.

You can find more details in the [link](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/changing-a-commit-message).

My change result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image you sent, it is not possible to change the commit name when committing via Power Apps. The commit name is always the name of the person who made the commit, as shown in the image.

This is because Power Apps uses Git version control, and Git does not allow you to change the commit name. Once a commit is made, it is immutable, meaning that it cannot be changed.

To change the commit message, you can use the `git commit --amend command`. This will open the commit message editor, where you can make changes to the message. However, you will not be able to change the commit name.

If you need to change the commit name, you will need to create a new commit. You can do this by making changes to your app and then saving them. Power Apps will automatically create a new commit when you save your changes.